# Drop rows not equal to values for unique items - pandas

Tags: pandas

I've got a df that contains various strings that are associated with unique values. For these unique values, I want to drop the rows that are not equal to a separate list, except for the last row.

Using below, the various string values in `Label` are associated with `Item`. So for each unique `Item`, there could be multiple rows in `Label` with various strings. I only want to keep the strings that are in `label_list`, except for the last row.

I'm not sure I can do this another way as the amount of strings not in `label_list` is too many to account for. The ordering van also vary. So for each unique value in `Item`, I really only want the last row and whatever rows that are in `label_list`.

```
label_list = ['A','B','C','D']

df = pd.DataFrame({  
    'Item' : [10,10,10,10,10,20,20,20],  
    'Label' : ['A','X','C','D','Y','A','B','X'],    
    'Count' : [80.0,80.0,200.0,210.0,260.0,260.0,300.0,310.0],                                      
    })

df = df[df['Label'].isin(label_list)]
```

Intended output:

```
   Item Label  Value
0    10     A   80.0
1    10     C  200.0
2    10     D  210.0
3    10     Y  260.0
4    20     A  260.0
5    20     B  300.0
6    20     X  310.0
```

Comment: What happens if the last row for a unique item is in label list? Do we keep all the items in label list, or we get the last row that is not in `label_list`? Regardless of if it's the last row or not?

Comment: The last row will always be different from values in `label_list`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This comes to mind as a quick and dirty solution:

`df = pd.concat([df[df['Label'].isin(label_list)],df.drop_duplicates('Item',keep='last')]).drop_duplicates(keep='first')`

We are appending the last row of each `Item` group, but in case the last row is duplicsted because it is also in `label_list` we are using drop duplicates for the concatenated outout too.

Comment: I'm getting a type error: `TypeError: first argument must be an iterable of pandas objects, you passed an object of type "DataFrame"`

Comment: Works well. Might sort to re-order `.sort_values(by = 'Item')`. There is prob no element solution here.

Answer (score 1):

1. check if `'Label'` `isin` `label_list`
2. check if rows are `duplicated`
3. boolean slice the dataframe

---

```
isin_ = df['Label'].isin(label_list)
duped = df.duplicated('Item', keep='last')

df[isin_ | ~duped]

   Item Label  Count
0    10     A   80.0
2    10     C  200.0
3    10     D  210.0
4    10     Y  260.0
5    20     A  260.0
6    20     B  300.0
7    20     X  310.0
```